# Ubuntu 20.04 slow download speed (wired network)

Tags: networking, internet

I have a 1Gbps connection and for some reason the download speed is very slow on Ubuntu 20.04 (using a wired connection not wifi). I tested several times using speedtest.net and got very different results on 2 different distros.

**Ubuntu 20.04 speedtest results**

```
Download speed  |  Upload speed
72 Mbps            450 Mbps
```

**I tested using Pop!_OS distro live CD and the results were totally different**

```
Download speed  |  Upload speed
996 Mbps           444 Mbps
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Pop OS is off-topic here, but they use *testing* (-proposed) packages & kernel) in their system, which isn't used by default in the *stable* oriented Ubuntu system. You didn't state any specifics as to software stack for Pop OS (were vague with 20.04, was it GA or HWE stack?) but that's where I'd be looking instead of *distro*.

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344532/wired-network-extremely-slow

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Thanks, that fixed the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wired network extremely slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344532/wired-network-extremely-slow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @FedonKadifeli I was able to fix the problem, this seems to be a known bug. The solution was to pass a kernel parameter to grub.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-5.10/+bug/1930754

```
The trick is to set the boot kernel parameter "pcie_aspm=off" in '/etc/default/grub'

Like this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash pcie_aspm=off"

After that run;

update-grub

pcie_aspm is some sort of power management thingie which probably puts my networkcontroller to sleep or something.
```

Comment: This is exactly my issue, Martin. I applied this answer and still no changes at all. My internet connection is still way lower than expected just like for OP.