# Ethernet Internet Speed Stuck at 100 Mbps for Gigabit Connection [Ubuntu 20.04 & 21.10]

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet, 21.10

My internet speed on Ethernet port is hard stuck at ~100 Mbps  on wifi I get more than 500 Mbps my internet runs at Gigabit and I have full bandwidth on Pop OS live, windows on the same machine and wire.

The problem is not with the wire and router but with Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.10 for certain.

I am using CAT 7 Cable

I've tried everything and even tried upgrading to 20.10 with no luck what could be the issue here

Here's my `lshw -c network` output

```
description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 38:f3:ab:60:5d:a7
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.03-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:59 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d1804000-d1804fff memory:d1800000-d1803fff
```

Here's `ethtools` output

```
Settings for eno1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

Other Info Ubuntu 21.10 x86_64 ,  5.13.0-35-generic, Lenovo Legion 5 15ARH05

Comment: @guiverc sorry my bad I edited it its pretty obvious to understand that It might have been a typo.

Comment: Nothing obvious. Tell us how you came to your conclusion  and show us speed test results and such. MBps is Megabytes per second, isn't it? Then you are good.

Comment: @DougSmythies How am I "good" I am getting 1/10 of speed I am getting on other operating systems on LAN, I am getting lower Internet speed on LAN compared to wifi 5x in my case .. I literally have said how I reached to the conclusion please read the description again.

Comment: @DougSmythies you want me to prove my internet speed ?

Comment: My best guess is that you are confusing megabytes per second with megabits per second. And I dispute that you are getting 500 Megabytes per second over wifi. And yes, please show your network speed test results. We are just trying to help here and sometimes it takes a little to really understand the posters issue.

Comment: @DougSmythies https://www.speedtest.net/result/12922392174.png on wifi  if you are still sceptical here https://imgur.com/0iHStEd do you really think I am confused about megabytes or bits ...? If you are not qualified enough to be of help please stop cluttering comments and stop wasting my time .

Comment: @DougSmythies here speedtest on LAN on windows https://www.speedtest.net/result/12922403583.png , and speedtest on LAN on ubuntu 21.10 https://www.speedtest.net/result/12922409494.png

Comment: Those screenshots are all megabits per second numbers, and believable. I see that you edited your question from MBps to Mbps. O.K.

Comment: Looking at the patterns across this site, this question will not receive an answer on account of the language being used. It is acceptable to attack *ideas*, but not *people*. It may be worth reconsidering some of your comments so that others are not put off and decide to volunteer their time elsewhere 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found a solution this might be helpful for others.

Known common bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-5.10/+bug/1930754

The solution is to pass a kernel parameter "pcie_aspm=off" to grub.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub 

# Edit the following line and add pcie_aspm=off

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash pcie_aspm=off"

sudo update-grub
```

Sources:

[Wired network extremely slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344532/wired-network-extremely-slow)

[Ubuntu 20.04 slow download speed (wired network)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347456/ubuntu-20-04-slow-download-speed-wired-network)

Comment: thank you, i was pulling my hair out...

Comment: This seemed to work for me. Thank you.