# Intel I219 Experiencing HUGE Package Loss

Tags: networking, kernel, intel, fedora, idle

There are some discussions and seems this issue has been solved. However, the literature is few. So I wrote this note and hope it will help others.

**Symptom**

Intel Ethernet Connection I219 Series, including I219-V and I219-LM, does not work on Linux, with about 1 Mb/s on speedtest.net and 30-50% ping loss within LAN. This is a problem in the kernel, so both Ubuntu and Fedora will suffer from the same problem. Users from 4.19 to 5.11 all reported this problem. Updating using apt does not help.

**Details**

- ping from another machine

```
$ ping -i 0.2 -W 0.2 -c 100 -s 1000 192.168.1.2
100 packets transmitted, 56 received, 44% packet loss, time 20195ms
```

- device information

```
# lspci -vvvnn -s 00:1f.6
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V [8086:15fa] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Ethernet Connection (14) I219-V [1558:50e1]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 129
    Region 0: Memory at 82380000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee00338  Data: 0000
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
# ethtool -i enp0s31f6
driver: e1000e
version: 5.11.0-40-generic
firmware-version: 0.4-4
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:00:1f.6
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason**

Power management shuts down the cache/memory of the network adapter (See [7] for more information).

**Workarounds**

- So I need to disable the power management. The work states for Intel devices are called C-State. C-States range from C0 to Cn. C0 indicates an active state (See [Intel User Guide/C-State](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/reference/energy-analysis-metrics-reference/c-state.html)). The first workaround is setting the maximum C-State not very high [3,4].

  ```
  vi /etc/default/grub
  # add intel_idle.max_cstate=1 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT after 
  "quite splash"
  # so that line looks like
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
  # then save and execute
  update-grub
  # then reboot, you can confirm this is applied by
  cat /proc/cmdline|grep intel
  cat /sys/module/intel_idle/parameters/max_cstate
  ```

  You can even set `max_cstate` to 0; [someone](https://www.codeblueprint.co.uk/2017/03/06/intel_idle-max_cstate-considered-harmful.html) do this.
- Change a flag about the network adapter's power control [5].

  ```
  # on my machine the default value is "auto"
  cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:16.0/power/control
  echo on > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:16.0/power/control
  # check it is "on" now
  cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:16.0/power/control
  ```

**Literatures**

1. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1652865 This is a report in Jan 2019. he is using 4.29 kernel. No solution was provided.
2. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213651 proposes

   - unload mei* (**does not work for me**)
   - BIOS settings -> System Management -> Intel AMT Capability, switch it from "Restrict MEBx Access" to "Disabled" (**does not work for me** -- my BIOS does not have this choice)
3. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213377 is about exactly the same problem. They propose

   - booting the same kernel(s) with "intel_idle.max_cstate=1" (For instructions see [How to set intel_idle.max_cstate=1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749349/how-to-set-intel-idle-max-cstate-1)) (**almost works** -- download speed and package loss is fixed but upload zero)
4. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1927925

   - They claim the solution in [3] works
   - Comment #93 explains why this bug happens, but too specialized; I cannot fully understand.
5. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-5.10/+bug/1930754

   - ```
     The trick is to set the boot kernel parameter "pcie_aspm=off" in '/etc/default/grub'
     Like this:
     GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash pcie_aspm=off"
     After that run;
     update-grub
     ```

     (**does not work for me**)
   - They confirm the solutions in [2] do not work.
   - `echo on | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:16.0/power/control` (**almost works** -- download speed and package loss is fixed but upload zero)
6. [Wired network extremely slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344532/wired-network-extremely-slow/1345978#1345978)

   - The asker did a lot of work, including reporting that **compiling driver ourselves is impossible**
   - None of the answers work for me.

Comment: Not sure if this counts as an answer, as you state that some suggested fixes do not work and others let you download but kill your uploads. It might make more sense to summarize this as parts of the question in the hopes that a member of the community has a solution that will allow you to download *and* upload with a reasonable transmission rate 

Comment: @matigo How about now? Does it more look like an answer?

Comment: Your solution did not fix it for me. I still had 53% packet loss after setting the max cstate to 1.