# "Wired network extremely slow" Workaround Not Presistent

Tags: networking, grub2, network-manager, internet

After upgrading or updating my Ubuntu to the latest, I noticed my Internet connection was very slow. After troubleshooting and testing, I learned that my latest ubuntu system's internet connection to the router was VERY SLOWER than expected - 9 to 10 mbp, but should be 90 to 100 mbp.

After doing Internet search for fixes or solution, I was able to speed up my system to router speed faster using the following workaround ([Wired network extremely slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344532/wired-network-extremely-slow) ) as follows.

Disabling `aspm` with `pcie_aspm=off` as a kernel option in /etc/default/grub, like this:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash pcie_aspm=off"

After that running:

update-grub

**However, this is not persistent. The changes don't stay effective. It sometimes for no apparent reason goes back to slower internet connection speed in the middle of running my system. At which point, I have to power down and turn on the system back again. Then, I get faster internet connection.**

Is there away to restart the network connection on the terminal for faster speed without having to completely reboot my system? And I have tried the answers that mentions terminal commands to do this and NONE of them works for me.

Comment: `sudo service network-manager restart`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried another device to make sure where is the problem? some times it's from the company that sell you the service, use [fast](https://fast.com/) page to check the speed using another device or a live CD.

try also to reset the router from the option's page 192.168.1.1 , then change the port of the cable , also pull it and reconnect in the device, if you found that no change and it's slow where ever so you need to call the company support.